# Display embedded PDF on webpage from AWS S3 bucket using Flask, Ajax, and boto3

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

Hello any help on this subject would be brilliant,

Say we have a simple webpage:

```
<div class="pdf"></div>
```

Our Flask/boto3 code

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id=keys.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                    aws_secret_access_key=keys.ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,  m  aws_session_token=keys.AWS_SESSION_TOKEN)

bucket = s3.Bucket(keys.S3_BUCKET_NAME)
object = bucket.Object('aa.pdf')
tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

@app.route("/display")
def display(bucket, object, tmp):
    file = s3.Object(keys.S3_BUCKET_NAME, 'aa.pdf').get()
    response = make_response(file['Body'].read())
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    return response
```

How would we then fetch the PDF from S3 and embed and display it on the webpage?

Viewing the console I can see that the object is being fetched as I am getting a 200 but it is not being displayed nor even downloaded.

When looking at the flask server **sometimes** I can also see an issue relating to **tmp**. More specifically, relating to incorrect permissions. Possibly relating to storing a file in the tmp directory

Any help would be greatly appreciated.